# Why should someone update to the 64 bit version of Vs Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All the info I can find basically says the 64 bit version is available but I can't find any info on what exactly that means? How is it different from the 32bit version?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you?

Comment: I thought 32 bit is faster. So, it looks like the only advantage is if you are working with extremely large files. So, the question begets, why would you?

Comment: 64-bit applications are equal or faster. There are security improvements not (fully) available to 32-bit applications. If you don't have a specific conflict that requires 32-bit applications, you should default to 64. (Note: VSCode uses electron.js which uses chromium)

Answer (score 8):

From the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15):

> - [Large file support](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_large-file-support) - Improved performance for large files, no size limit on 64-bit machines.
> - [64-bit Windows builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_windows-64-bit) - Use your computer's full address space with the 64-bit builds.

For example, to open large files (the 32 bit version has now a limit of 300 MB, previously it was 50 MB) you'll need the 64 bit version.

Comment: This is a great start to an answer. I think that it needs to be expanded to explain use cases where one would be better than the other to help guide users to picking one over the other.

Comment: @Guy: What use cases do you have in mind? My current recommendation would be pretty straightforward: if you have a 64 bit system, use it and install the 64 bit version of VSCode. It gives you a better overall performance. Maybe you won't really need it, but it doesn't harm.

Comment: If there are no downsides to the 64-bit version then I my request for comparison of one over the other is unwarranted. I thought I read that 64-bit was slower. If that's not the case then no comparison is needed.

Comment: What about plugins or extensions? Would some be compatible with 32bit but not 64bit?

Comment: I don't want my files larger than 300 MB, I stick to to 32 for now